# Visual Studio for Mac, Xamarin Forms with Refit: exited with code 1

Tags: xamarin.forms, mono, visual-studio-mac

in my `Xamarin` project I added `Refit` ([site here](https://github.com/paulcbetts/refit)): the solution has `Profile 111`. If I compile the project I receive this error:

> /Users/mypc/.nuget/packages/refit/3.1.0/build/netstandard1.1/refit.targets(5,5):
>   Error MSB3073: The command "mono
>   "/Users/mypc/.nuget/packages/refit/3.1.0/build/netstandard1.1/../../tools/InterfaceStubGenerator.exe"
>   "obj/Debug//RefitStubs.g.cs"
>   "/Users/mypc/Projects/myproject/App/Common"
>   "obj/Debug/RefitParams.rsp"" exited with code 1. (MSB3073)
>   (MyPolicy.Common)

I tried to change in `refit.targets` the path with this [instruction](https://github.com/paulcbetts/refit/issues/192):

- Open refit.targets
- Line 30: `<RefitExecCmd>mono "$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory) ..snip.. </RefitExecCmd>`
- Change mono path to it's absolute location in my case: `/usr/local/bin/mono`
- Like this: `<RefitExecCmd>/usr/local/bin/mono "$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory) ..snip.. </RefitExecCmd>`

I also read this post on [BugZilla](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=34564). It didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: You can use Refit 4.x by changing your Forms-based PCL to NetStd 1.5 and updating Xamarin.Forms to 2.4.x (in Prerelease right now) Make sure that you add Refit to your application projects also....

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem. I removed completely the project that has the problem and I recreated it. After that operation, the solution is build.